# getpriority returning different value on different hosts with same kernel version

Tags: limit, nice, priority

I am running `centos 6.6` on same type of hardware with kernel version `"2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64"`

Has anybody seen this why the below code when compiled and executed gives a different value on two different hosts (of same hardware class). The different value being 0 or 19.

```
 #include <sys/resource.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int prio;
        int incr;

        errno = 0;
        prio = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
        printf("%d is prio \n", prio);
}
```

host 1:

```
$ gcc -o mynice mynice.c
$ ./mynice
0 is prio
$
```

host 2:

```
$ scp host1:~/mynice ~/
$ ./mynice
19 is prio
```

I have checked my limits.conf and others under /etc/security and I did not see anything interesting that differ about this in any config files either.

Output of `ulimit -a` on both the machines for the user has no difference.

Comment: what are actual limits do `ulimit -a` show? Please include the output into your post.

Comment: Just added the note that output of 'ulimit -a' has no difference for the same user on different machines. @siblynx please do let me know if you meant the same thing

Comment: @gilles any ideas?

Comment: OK not related to limits in any way, you just have a forced 19 nice value on host 2.

Comment: Check the output of `ps -eHo nice,pid,args` to see at which level in your ancestry the niceness was set to 19 which could give you a clue to what did it.

Comment: Check the pam configuration, pam_umask for instance can also set the niceness (`pri=` directives)

Comment: umask is 0022 for pam sshd session for both the nodes

Comment: It wasn't really about the `umask`, but about the `pam_umask` PAM module that can also set the niceness. See /etc/pam.conf or /etc/pam.d/*. Also what does `ps -eHo nice,pid,args` tell you? Which are the processes with 19 niceness?. How are those shells where you run that command started? Over ssh, in terminal emulators in a X11 session?